# If I buy official tickets online to Louvre Museum, can I skip the queue?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, bookings, paris, the-louvre

I thought of purchasing the tickets for Louvre Museum from its [official site](http://www.louvre.fr/en/buy-tickets), but there is no mention about ability to skip the queues. I read that there is a huge queue to enter.

Does buying official Louvre tickets in advance allow me to skip these lines?

Why do I need to pick a time when I do the booking? Does it mean that I have to be there at that time to enter the Museum?

Answer (score 4):

It says so on the link you've shared:

"Book tickets online
**To avoid waiting in line, you can buy your tickets online.***
* Online ticketing service available in French, English, and Spanish.
Enjoy your visit!"

So the answer to your question is, YES, you can avoid the queues.

Timed tickets require you to enter within the stipulated window. That's how they ensure pre-bookers aren't required to stand in lines.

Comment: Yes, I saw this line but there aren't any mention about skipping the queues after that. I just wanted to know whether there is anyone who has tried this before. Actually there is no stipulated window, they have only asked for an access hour. I assume that this means we can enter at that time and spend any amount of time inside the museum. Also what happens if we couldn't make it on the access hour we booked the ticket?

Comment: Remember that there are two or even three queues at most of the entrances. One to the 'no need for tickets, just the security check' and one for 'security and tickets'. There might be a third 'queue' for groups. So check out that you are in the right queue.

Comment: The 'got a ticket already' queue is always much,  much shorter than the 'need a ticket' queue.